# Django form posts data with no errors, but does not register as 'is_valid'

Tags: python, django, forms, post

I am creating my first Django form and I can see the data passing successfully to the console through my logging, but it does not save to the database because the post data is not registering as 'is_valid'. I would love to know why.

**Template** - newpost.html

```
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{newPost.as_p}}
<input type='submit' value='Create Post'>
</form>
```

**Form** - forms.py

```
class PostEntry(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = [
            "image",
            "body",
            "user",
            "slug",
            "publish"
        ]
```

**Model** - models.py

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="")
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True, default=rand_slug())
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/posts/%s/%s' % (self.user, self.slug)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

**View** - views.py

```
def NewJournalDetail(request):
    newPost = PostEntry()
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST.get("body")) # successful
        print(request.POST.get("image")) # successful
        print(request.POST.get("slug")) # successful
        print(request.POST.get("user")) # successful
        print(request.POST.get("publish")) # successful
        if newPost.is_valid(): # NOT successful
            print(newPost)
            instance = newPost.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
        else:
            print('not valid')
            print(newPost.errors) # NO errors
    context = {
        "newPost": newPost,
    }
    return render(request, "newpost.html", context)
```

**Console Output**

```
[23/Nov/2017 10:19:51] "GET /create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 894
this is text from the body
image.PNG
1FP2is
1
on
not valid

[23/Nov/2017 10:19:57] "POST /create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 894
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any data to the form. You must instantiate the form differently for `POST` and `GET` requests. For a `GET` request, it just instantiates the form:

```
form = PostEntry()
```

For a POST request, it should pass the request data to the form:

```
form = PostEntry(request.POST)
```

So your view would look like this:

```
def NewJournalDetail(request):    
    if request.method == "POST":
        newPost = PostEntry(request.POST)
        if newPost.is_valid():
            instance = newPost.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/someurl/')
    else:  # not a POST request
        newPost = PostEntry()
    context = {
        "newPost": newPost,
    }
    return render(request, "newpost.html", context)
```

On a side note, I've stuck with your code style for this example, but the common naming convention for methods and variables in Python is lowercase with underscores, e.g. `new_journal_detail` or `new_post`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I see now why the data wasn't making it to the form. Makes sense. I also appreciate the tip on the naming convention. Thanks again.